# Different ways for sending request context with HttpResponseRedirect in django

Tags: django, redirect, payment-gateway, httpresponse, django-sessions

I have a django app and implemented payment gateway functionality. 
Now what i was trying is

After successful transation, need to do redirect user to another page that shows the response details so i am using `HttpresponseRedirect` to redirect the page, but i have the variable `response` in the view that contains reponse details, so i need to send this variable as the context to the redirecting url that renders template, so that i can use that response variable to display the results.

so for the above functionality, i got three methods

1. Sending the variable as the query parameter(which is not safe in this method because it is sensitive credit card transaction details)
2. Using session framework, which is not working in my case, the code is below
3. Django messaging framework(which is not so useful in this case)

**views.py**

```
def payment(request):
    amount = 1
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CreditCardForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            ...........
            ........... 
            response = stripe.payment_purchase(amount,data) 
            request.session['response'] = response
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('paygate:payment_success'))
    else:
        form = CreditCardForm(initial={'number':'4242424242424242'})
    return render_to_response('payment/stripe_payment_form.html',{'form': form,
                                             'response':response,},
                                             context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**payment_success url view**

```
class PaymentSuccess(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'payment/payment_success.html'
```

I tried to access `response` variable in the template, but displaying nothing

**payment_success.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block main_title %}Payment{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Success{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <h1>Response Details</h1>
  <p>Your status is <span>{{ request.session.response }}</span></p>
{% endblock %}
```

So can anyone please let me know the various different safe and secure ways to send context variables(in this case `credit card payment details`) to redirecting url using `HttpResponseRedirect` method

Comment: You should have shown the code for the `payment_success` view.

Comment: thats just a template class view with one attribute like template_name, anyway edited above code

Comment: So hang on, what's responsible for rendering `payment_template.html`?

Comment: Sorry thats a typo !!!!, i had edited the template name above...

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a 4. possible item in your list, that I suggest to use.

The safest and most pragmatic way of accomplish what you want is to have a successful view showing the actual results stored in your database.

The idea behind this is:

`payment` view is an action that a user performs on your database.

`payment_success` view is a way of telling the user that the action was performed successfully and with the the input the user desired.

Likewise, the best way of showing that the action is correct is to show its result on the database, i.e. what it is now stored on the database regarding that action.

Comment: but in this case, i `dont want to store the response` that came as result from the `payment gateway`, i want to simply show the response to the user by redirecting to some other page, can we do this ? or it is not possible ?, Also whether we can store the object in session variable as above ?